# Wrapper class around list to track if new changes happened to it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need something on the lines of below:

```
class CustomList(List):
    def __init__(self):
        self.changeID = 0  # This value increases whenever a value is changed in the custom list
```

I'm looking for a very computationally cheap way to find out if the list changed it's state from the previous time I accessed it. And the way of doing it could be to update some `changeID` associated with the list everytime it's value is updated.
A change to list is one of the following:
- Value was appended
- Value was deleted
- Value was replaced at a certain index

And what I'd expect is the following:

```
l1 = CustomList()  # changeId = 0 at beginning
l1.append(2)       # changeId updates to 1
l1.append(7)       # changeId updates to 2
l1.append(30)      # changeId updates to 3
l1[1] = 9          # changeId updates to 4 . l1 = [2, 9, 30]
del l1[0]          # changeId updates to 5 . l1 = [9,30]
l1.remove(9)       # changeId updates to 6 . l1 = [30]
l1.pop()           # changeId updates to 7 . l1 = []

print(l1.changeID)  # changeID needs to be accessible via the object (of course)
```

I tried to write some code for this, but was unsuccessful. Kindly help.

Comment: Hi, even if it was not a success, maybe you could share it with us (you might have been close to a solution) ;-).

Comment: :) Let me compile my code in a format I could put it here..

Answer (score 2):

You will have to patch individual methods (I may have missed some, do your research):

```
class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.change_id = 0
        super().__init__()

    def append(self, obj):
        self.change_id += 1
        super().append(obj)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.change_id += 1
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

    def remove(self, obj):
        self.change_id += 1
        super().remove(obj)

    def pop(self, index):
        self.change_id += 1
        super().pop(index)

    def insert(self, index, obj):
        self.chgange_id += 1
        super().insert(index, obj)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.change_id += 1
        super().__delitem__(key)

l1 = CustomList()
l1.append(2)
l1.append(7)
l1.append(30)
l1[1] = 9
del l1[0]
l1.remove(9)
l1.pop(0)
print(l1.change_id)
# 7
```

This code has a lot of repetition, we could use a decorator:

```
def increase_change_counter(func):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.change_id += 1
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner

class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.change_id = 0
        super().__init__()

    @increase_change_counter
    def append(self, obj):
        super().append(obj)

    @increase_change_counter
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

    @increase_change_counter
    def remove(self, obj):
        super().remove(obj)

    @increase_change_counter
    def pop(self, index):
        super().pop(index)

    @increase_change_counter
    def insert(self, index, obj):
        super().insert(index, obj)

    @increase_change_counter
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        super().__delitem__(key)


l1 = CustomList()
l1.append(2)
l1.append(7)
l1.append(30)
l1[1] = 9
del l1[0]
l1.remove(9)
l1.pop(0)
print(l1.change_id)
# 7
```

This is still too long for apparently a simple task.

We could try this:

```
class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.change_id = 0
        super().__init__()

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item in ('append', 'remove', 'pop', 'insert'):
            self.change_id += 1
        return super().__getattribute__(item)
```

But `l1[1] = 9` and `del l1[0]` will not be caught by `__getattribute__`.

So maybe a combination:

```
def increase_change_counter(func):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.change_id += 1
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner

class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.change_id = 0
        super().__init__()

    @increase_change_counter
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

    @increase_change_counter
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        super().__delitem__(key)

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item in ('append', 'remove', 'pop', 'insert'):
            self.change_id += 1
        return super().__getattribute__(item)

l1 = CustomList()
l1.append(2)
l1.append(7)
l1.append(30)
l1[1] = 9
del l1[0]
l1.remove(9)
l1.pop(0)
print(l1.change_id)
# 7
```